# Четность и нечетность числа, не понимаю что происходит

Tags: java

Парни, такая беда. Я не понимаю в чем тут ошибка. Мне нужно, чтобы в цикле, на выходе 2 числа были нечетными, но почему то, цикл заканчивается, когда одно число четное, на второе он забивает. Я пробовал как && , так и & , я понимаю их разницу, но это не помогает. Просьба не выпендриваться, а доходчиво обьяснить, что я тут делаю не так. С меня печенье, у меня мама их вкусно готовит

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i,j;

        do {
            i = (int) (Math.random()*10);
            j = (int) (Math.random()*10);
        } while ((i % 2) != 0 & (j % 2) != 0);

        System.out.println("i = " + i + " j = " + j);
    }
}
```

Вывод такой (Несколько примеров)

```
i = 3 j = 2
i = 6 j = 7
i = 4 j = 3
```

Comment: на выходе 2 числа были нечетными: `while ((i % 2) == 0 || (j % 2) == 0)`

Comment: `(i % 2) == 0` - чётность, `(i % 2) > 0` - нечётность.

Comment: зачем получать два случайных значения парами? (чтобы они были нечетными и сгенерированными подряд)

Comment: @dgzargo, вы имеете в виду, что эффективнее генерировать числа по отдельности?

Comment: @aiDOSx `a=2n+1` - формула нечетных чисел (если рандом в примере - рандом на практике); но если генерировать их по отдельности - вероятность словить два нечетных выше, способ быстрее

Comment: @aiDOSx вы "ловите" их вместе - вероятность 1/4; по-отдельности: 1/2 & 1/2. ускорение за счет обрыва итерации если первое число не подходит

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка в алгоритме. Нужно делать цикл от обратного, т.е. пока хотя бы одно число четное :

```
   do {
        i = (int) (Math.random()*10);
        j = (int) (Math.random()*10);
    } while ((i % 2) == 0 || (j % 2) == 0);
```

Comment: А, все, понял свою ошибку, алгоритм работал пока оба числа становились нечетными и переставал работать, когда одно из них переставало быть нечетным. Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

я бы попробовал `while (!(( ((i % 2) != 0) && ((j % 2) != 0) ))`
но рекомендую использовать формулу

```
int i = ((int) (Math.random()*10))*2+1;
int j = ((int) (Math.random()*10))*2+1;
```

тут числа будут генерироваться сразу нечетными
`a = 2n + 1`

Comment: "тут числа будут генерироваться сразу нечетными" - например, `random` вернул 0.05

Comment: @Igor странно что я ошибся. это очень простая операция. исправил, кажется